# Android SQLite - Using where args to delete by _id does NOT delete

Tags: android, sqlite

When I execute the following, isDeleted is false.

```
String [] whereArgs = {new Integer(userId).toString()};
boolean isDeleted = db.delete("users_fts", "_id = ?", whereArgs ) > 0;
```

I have verified that the userId, exists in the users_fts table. (I can do a select). Also, the below query to delete works. isDeleted is true

```
boolean isDeleted = db.delete("users_fts", "_id = 1361", null ) > 0;
```

users_fts is a Virtual Table (if that makes any difference).

What is it that I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I tried a select using db.query and arguments. The cursor count is 0

```
Cursor c = db.query("users_fts",null,"_id = ?",whereArgs,null,null,null);
```

But if I did the following, cursor count is 1

```
Cursor c = db.query("users_fts",null,"_id = " + userId,null,null,null,null);
```

UPDATE:

Snapshot of whereArgs

[image: Snapshot of whereArgs]

Comment: you can try to use String.valueOf(userId) instead of new Integer(userId).toString()

Comment: what is the type of userId variable?

Comment: as @mrtn suggest use String.valueOf(userId) .

Comment: I have also tired String.valueOf(userId). userId is int datatype. No luck.

Comment: The ID is an integer. Why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: @CL. Since whereArgs is a string array, I convert it. So what should whereArgs look like? Can you give an example of how you would do it?

Comment: @CL. Ah OK. I didn't expect that int params couldn't be used in whereArgs. Thanks for that link.